# Can't restore partition table

Tags: windows, partitioning, gparted, partition-recovery

I wanted to install Ubuntu on my Asus ROG laptop. I previously installed a second NVME SSD and used it under Windows to store stuff. I did, however, leave ~200GiB free for a Linux installation.

When I tried to install Ubuntu on the second disk, it couldn't use the partition table that was created by Windows, so I had to remove it. I ACCIDENTALLY REMOVED THE WRONG ONE!!! Now I don't have Windows anymore, and I wish to restore it.

I carefully installed Ubuntu on the second drive without touching the first. Then, I tried to run `gpart`, `gparted` and `testdisk`. The first two kinda failed (I can re-run stuff if it helps), but the latter seems to have succeeded - it DID find all the partitions. However, when I select all of them for restoration, it doesn't accept my choice.

Please help me! I've spent many hours on this already, and I'm clueless on how to proceed. Thanks!

`gpart`'s output was:

[image: gpart1]
[image: gpart2]

`testdisk`:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: (1) [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). (2) I cannot spot meaningful differences between the three screenshots posted under `testdisk`. What am I missing? What did you want to show by posting *three* screenshots (i.e. not just one)? (3) What happens when you select the deleted partition (marked with `D`) and press `Enter` to continue?

Comment: Restore the disk from the last full image you made. That would restore *all* partitions and the data on them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: Please don't post images of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future people who might find this useful. The problem was that I used the suggested "**Intel**" partition table which means **MBR**, and **MBR** does not allow over 4 "primary" partitions. The secret was to use create a **GPT** partition table that allows for more than 4 partitions.

The error could've been made clearer by `testdisk` (not just writing **BAD**).